# Thumbnail images on home page (grid) now appearing blurry. How to correct that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I don't know if this looks silly but since morning I have been unable to correct this error that has suddenly crept up on my blog site [www.candidopinions.in](http://www.candidopinions.in)

I have a grid view template in which the featured image in a blogpost appears on the home page as resized thumbnails (8 images on each home page). This blog and the template that I am using have been live since 1.5 years and until last night, the thumbnail images were appearing sharp. 
I don't know what happened but since morning the thumbnail images have been appearing blurry/pixelated, although inside the blogpost, they appear in good quality. I am not sure if some javascript code got deleted accidentally or some js file that I uploaded on my site isn't accessible anymore.

I guess, this is the code meant for resizing of the thumbnail images on the home page:

```html
<article class='post hentry'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
         <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
          <script type='text/javascript'>
          //<![CDATA[
          function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title) {var image_size=340; image_tag='<img src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'" class="postthumb" width="370" height="200" alt="'+post_title+'" title="'+post_title+'"/>'; if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return ""; }
          //]]>
          </script>

          <a expr:href='data:post.url'><script type='text/javascript'>
          document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
          </script></a>
          <b:else/>
          <a expr:href='data:post.url'><img class='postthumb' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:title='data:post.title' height='100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KPszJjd3eow/Vs0v2crutdI/AAAAAAAAA1Y/T2ulIts0CGc/s1600/candid-opinions-logo.png' width='150'/></a>
          </b:if>
```

I tried to increase the value of image_size=340 and so also width and height, but for no result. I also tried replacing s72-c to s1600 but to no avail. Sharing a screenshot here of the current blurry image thumbnails

Currently thumbnail images appearing blurry screenshot

[image: xx]

I have also checked with the Internet web archive and this is how it used to look until last night -

Previously the thumbnail images used to be sharp and clearer screenshot

[image: xxx]

Kindly someone help me out as I am unable to know where lies the fault. Any guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between image resize parameter `/s72-c/` in javascript code and images resize parameters `/s72-c-k-no/` on homepage.

To avoid that remove `/` from javascript snippet `'/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/'`

**Try this**

```
<article class='post hentry'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
         <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
          <script type='text/javascript'>
          //<![CDATA[
          function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title) {var image_size=340; image_tag='<img src="'+image_url.replace('s72-c','s'+image_size+'-c')+'" class="postthumb" width="370" height="200" alt="'+post_title+'" title="'+post_title+'"/>'; if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return ""; }
          //]]>
          </script>

          <a expr:href='data:post.url'><script type='text/javascript'>
          document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
          </script></a>
          <b:else/>
          <a expr:href='data:post.url'><img class='postthumb' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:title='data:post.title' height='100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KPszJjd3eow/Vs0v2crutdI/AAAAAAAAA1Y/T2ulIts0CGc/s1600/candid-opinions-logo.png' width='150'/></a>
          </b:if>
```

**Update**

**Alternatively** If you need a perfect method without JavaScript and to avoid any similer changes by Blogger in the future you can use [resizeImage](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/4R_sAkgZH9I) operator which can be usesed to change the size of the image server-side

Replace the JavaScript code above with

```
<img expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 340)'/>
```

**Your code**

```
<b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
        <img expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 340)' expr:title='data:post.title' class='postthumb' width='370' height='200' expr:alt='data:post.title'/>
    </a>
<b:else/>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
        <img class='postthumb' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:title='data:post.title' height='100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KPszJjd3eow/Vs0v2crutdI/AAAAAAAAA1Y/T2ulIts0CGc/s1600/candid-opinions-logo.png' width='150'/>
    </a>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much Bassam, this really worked like a charm. I had been trying to correct this since morning. My heartfelt thanks once again :)

Comment: Hello Bassam, I tried your new edited code (without the javascript code) but the grid images are not displaying in proper size. This is how they are turning up:

Comment: @A.Kumar Resize images without javascript is good for performance because you don't need to load images two times with javascript delay caused by parsing, manipulation and rendering. In your case you need to set proper height. you have `.post img` in your  css code. it overrides height attribute `height='200'`so you can remove `height: 100%;` or change it to the desired height `height: 200px;`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [resize operator](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/4R_sAkgZH9I) for images provided by Blogger would be much better solution. It will make your code immune to any future changes that might occur in thumbnail URL parameters because the resized thumbnail URL will get generated by Blogger itself (Not via JavaScript Regex matching). Your code will change as follows -

```
<b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url, post_title) {
        image_tag = '<img src="' + image_url +
            '" class="postthumb" width="370" height="200" alt="' + post_title + '" title="' + post_title + '"/>';
        if(image_url != "") return image_tag;
        else return "";
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<a expr:href='data:post.url'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl,340,"1:1")'/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
    </script>
</a>
<b:else/>
<a expr:href='data:post.url'><img class='postthumb' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:title='data:post.title' height='100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KPszJjd3eow/Vs0v2crutdI/AAAAAAAAA1Y/T2ulIts0CGc/s1600/candid-opinions-logo.png'
        width='150' /></a>
</b:if>
```

As you will notice, the `.replace` operation has been completed removed. Instead, now you will be directly able to set the thumbnail dimensions via the tag itself - `<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 340,"1:1")'/>`

Regarding the information about the various parameters that `resizeImage` function takes -

> The resizeImage operator takes 3 parameters:
>
> ***imageUrl*** - The original URL of the resizable image.
>
> ***newSize*** - The new width of the image
>
> ***(optional) ratio*** - The integer ratio of width to height for the resized image, e.g. “1:1” or “4:3”
>
> **NOTES**
>
> - If the imageUrl parameter is not a resizable image, the resizeImage
>     function will return the original imageUrl.
> - The ratio must be integer
>     numbers.
> - If the ratio is provided, the image will be cropped to those
>     exact dimensions.

Comment: Thank you Prayag for taking time to suggest the changes. But when I tried replacing this code, it givesan error message:

Comment: "Error parsing XML, line 2701, column 142: Attribute name "post.title" associated with an element type "data:" must be followed by the ' = ' character."

Comment: @A.Kumar there was an incorrect spacing in the tag which lead to this. I have made the changes ( `<data: post.title/>` replaced with `<data:post.title/>` ). and you can try the code now

Comment: Yes, this time it's working nicely. Thank you so much Prayag for the help :) I have replaced the old code with this one. Very much appreciated :)

Comment: I think no need to use JavaScript with resizeImage operator in this case.

Comment: Yes @Bassam , we can make it work without using Javascript, by directly calling the `resizeImage` function from the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag. The code will look like - `<a expr:href='data:post.url'><img class='postthumb' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl,340,"1:1")' /></a>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple issue of image compression, you might consider looking up these images and searching out a file with the proper dimensions,

the source image file for one of the images on your site:
https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-MPPETleu560/WLb8qTSGMpI/AAAAAAAABo8/NrYKhoqQj_0yqBCNRS1PstLIqkhnT_uvwCLcB/s72-c-k-no/matar-rice-paneer-makhni.jpg

Notice how small the image really is, Consider switching servers for your image files and retaining images in a .png format rather than .jpg.

Comment: I have used quite a few PNG images as well. But this issue of blurred thumbnails is only been seen on the home page. Inside the posts, the similarly sized thumbnail images are coming our nice and clear. Moreover since the last 1.5 years, I never faced this problem. It's only this morning that it has started.

Comment: It's because your homepage is calling a much lower resolution image than your individual posts, did you recently change anything related to your image database?  If not, try having your homepage reference the images available shown in the previous version in the webservice archive.

Comment: Yes, I made a few changes in the template code recently but they weren't related to the template's css or javascript, I only added a few keywords in the meta description. By the way, can you please tell me how do I and where to change the code so that the homepage would call a higher resolution image? That will be  a great help. Because all of my recent images although are in jpg format are sized 1400 x 1100 pixels approximately. I am still wondering what am I doing differently now that previously the homepage used to have sharper thumbnails.