# Thumbnail images on home page (Blogspot Blog) suddenly blurry?

Tags: javascript, templates, blogger, blogspot

I am using the following template for my blogspot blog: http://bold-bthemez.blogspot.com/ as you can see the images on the front page are suddenly blurry (they were fine until yesterday, I have no idea why this suddenly changed). I am guessing this has something to do with Javascript, as something similar happened to someone else who asked a question here, but the answer did not work for my blog (I am referring to this question: [Thumbnail images on home page (grid) now appearing blurry. How to correct that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558143/thumbnail-images-on-home-page-grid-now-appearing-blurry-how-to-correct-that))

Please help, I tried for 4 hours to fix this and can't do it...

Comment: the images are really small ... what do you expect?

Comment: 72x72 thumbnails of 1600x1200 images blown up to 375x210 are not blurry, they're pixelated - nothing to do with javascript, everything to do with the images being (ab)used

Comment: I see you've changed them now - oh wait - you didn't - how bizzare!!! they were better just now!

Comment: Is that link in the question your site? because if not, there's something absolutely screwy with that theme

Comment: No this isn't my website but this is the theme I am using and everything was fine with those images until yesterday, they were not pixelated at all, but they are now, and I don't understand why this changed or how to fix it

Comment: On a separate note, what exactly is screwy with the theme? I thought it was just my theme that displays the image pixelated, but there are other blogspot themes who seem to be doing the same thing

Comment: So I just refreshed the page it is now displaying the images fine on my Macbook Air, but on my other Macbook it is still pixelated on chrome but working fine on Safari?? I'm so confused

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened because the structure of the Post's Thumbnail URL (which is accessible via the layout tag - `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>`) was changed by Blogger (Specifically, `s72-c` was changed to `s72-c-k-no`) The problem occurred because a lot of Blogger Template creators used regex matching for resizing images (from the default resolution of 72x72px to larger sizes). As the regex matching condition was no longer being met, the image resizing script didn't alter the image resolution and default 72x72px was being rendered (which appeared pixelated/blurred as it as being stretched to a much larger resolution than its original resolution)

But, as this solution (of using regex matching to change Thumbnail resolution) was used by a lot of blogs, this affected many users. In light of this, **Blogger reverted back the changes they did to the Thumbnail URL**. Here is the [post from a Google employee](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/6vckGtj6-Us/bLT9RzT1AgAJ) regarding this matter in the Official Blogger Forum -

> Hi everyone,
>
> It's likely that the change that caused this problem will be reverted
>   in the near future, so I would recommend a backward-compatible
>   solution to the problem. If this message/post does not make any sense
>   to you, it may make sense to your custom template's author, so let
>   them know about it, in case Blogger makes any similar changes in the
>   future.
>
> Blogger's Layouts engine (the template language) has a native
>   'resizeImage' operator, which can be used to change the size of the
>   thumbnails. Lots of you have custom templates that are using a
>   javascript regex to change the value. (String replacement of 's72-c').
>   This can be better achieved server-side, by replacing the URL part.
>
> This tag
>
> `<data:post.thumbnailUrl />`
>
> Can be changed for a resizeImage operation, which takes the new width
>   you want, and the new width:height ratio. e.g. for a 200x200 image
>
> `<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 200, "1:1")' />`
>
> More documentation on the resizeImage operator can be found here:
>   https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/4R_sAkgZH9I
>
> Hope this helps.